# NameError: global name 'unique' is not defined

Tags: python

I am calling the function unique from the following function and getting the above error message.

```
isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed)
     55     '''
     56     letters = 0
---> 57     a = unique(secretWord)
     58     for char in a:
     59         if char in lettersGuessed:

NameError: global name 'unique' is not defined
```

when I call unique simply typing in Python,  it works fine.  EG

```
secretWord
Out[85]: 'revenging'

unique(secretWord)
Out[86]: 
array(['e', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 'v'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Why is it not recognised within the function?  (apologies if this is a novice error).

Comment: what is unique supposed to be?

Comment: The error means exactly as it states. You haven't defined a unique function.

Comment: unique is built in.  I didn't define it.  As I said typing it straight into python as in the second example works fine.  It lists the unique characters of a string in order

Comment: PS thank you for responding so quickly

Answer (score 5):

`unique` is *not* built in; that's [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

The only reason `unique` works in your IPython console is that something you've done -- such as running IPython in pylab mode -- has imported all of `numpy` into scope, which is a bad idea.

```
In [1]: unique(list("abcb"))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-83e4d9fe063f> in <module>()
----> 1 unique(list("abcb"))

NameError: name 'unique' is not defined

In [2]: from numpy import *   # don't do this

In [3]: unique(list("abcb"))
Out[3]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Doing this replaces `all` and `any` and many other functions with their numpy versions, which don't work the same way as the standard ones, and can even give opposite results sometimes, and so should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: I'm running the editor from Canopy.  The only module I have imported is 'math'  however numpy seems to be pre-installed.  I have tried changing unique to numpy.unique in the function but it is now saying "NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined".  I tried explicitly importing numpy but the result is the same.

Comment: @user326827: if you absolutely want to use it, then adding `import numpy` at the start of the file and using `numpy.unique` should work.  But unless you need a sorted unique, there's no reason to be using in the first place (and frankly there are non-numpy ways to do it anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a builtin to get unique letters you should use [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), there is nothing in your code that suggests a need for a numpy array:

```
In [3]: secretWord  = 'revenging'

In [4]: set(secretWord)
Out[4]: {'e', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 'v'}
```

Comment: @user326827, no worries, the biggest advantage with sets is lookups are `0(1)` as opposed to linear with lists etc.. so using the set as the thing to check for membership is usually a good idea. Enjoy 6.001x